# Is there a way to iterate a subtraction starting from the next element in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, for-loop, indexing

I have two lists. I am trying to create a code that will allow me to do the following:

```
import numpy as np
a = [1,3,5,10,15]
b = [2,4,9,12,19]
```

I want to always start from the second element in the list a and subtract the first element from the list b. Like,

`3-2=1, 5-4=1, 10-9=1, 15-12=3, NAN`

My expected output is a list c that looks like this:

```
c=[1,1,1,3,NAN] or c=[1,1,1,3]
```

So far, I come up with this solution:

```
c = np.zeros(len["b"])
for x in range(len["b"]):
    c[x] = a[x+1]-b[x]
```

but it results in this error:

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

Could you please give me some hint or direction how to deal with the error and the creation of list c?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You mean `len("b")` instead of `len["b"]`?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM `len(b)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just slice your lists/arrays:

```
import numpy as np

a = [1,3,5,10,15]
b = [2,4,9,12,19] 

c = np.subtract(a[1:], b[:-1])
```

Output: `array([1, 1, 1, 3])`

Or:

```
c = np.r_[a[1:], np.nan]-b
```

Output: `array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  3., nan])`

Fix of your solution (but don't use it, you shouldn't use loops with [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy)):

```
c = np.zeros(len(b))
for x in range(len(b)-1):
    c[x] = a[x+1]-b[x]
# array([1., 1., 1., 3., 0.])
```

Comment: Thank you, now I understand it more! Greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

you're getting an error cuz you're trying to subscript `[]` a built in function `len` so instead of `len["b"]` it should be `len(b)`

so it should be

```py
c = np.zeros(len(b))
for x in range(len(b)-1):
    c[x] = a[x+1]-b[x]
```

we can also use `zip` and list comprehension

```py
c = [an-bn for an, bn in zip(a[1:], b)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a little correction:

`(len(b))` instead of `(len["b"])`  # see there should be no quotes and no square bractkets, only round parenthesis.

```
import numpy as np
a = [1,3,5,10,15]
b = [2,4,9,12,19] 

c = np.zeros(len(b))
for x in range(len(b)-1):
    c[x] = a[x+1]-b[x]

print(c)
#array([1., 1., 1., 3., 0.])
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's focus a bit more on the debugging process:

```
In [145]: a = [1,3,5,10,15]
     ...: b = [2,4,9,12,19]

In [146]: c = np.zeros(len["b"])
     ...: for x in range(len["b"]):
     ...:     c[x] = a[x+1]-b[x]
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

I was kind of expecting the error to point to the error line.  As others point out `len["b"]` is wrong.

But since the error isn't more specific, let's try the first line of your code by itself:

```
In [147]: c = np.zeros(len["b"])
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

and further isolate the argument to `np.zeros`:

```
In [148]: len["b"]
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

So there are two problems here.  `len` is a basic python function.  You call a function with `()`.  `[]` for indexing.  And `len("b")` won't help, since `"b"` is a string of length 1.  The string "b", is not the same as the variable `b` that you defined as a list.

Correcting that `len` use, we get a different error - because `x+1` indexes too far in `a`:

```
In [150]: c = np.zeros(len(b))
     ...: for x in range(len(b)):
     ...:     c[x] = a[x+1]-b[x]
     ...:     
IndexError: list index out of range
```

One fix is to make a shorter `c`

```
In [157]: c = np.zeros(len(b)-1)
     ...: for x in range(len(c)):
     ...:     c[x] = a[x+1]-b[x]
     ...: c
Out[157]: array([1., 1., 1., 3.])
```

If you want the trailing `nan`, you could start with a `c` that is full of `nan`:

```
In [160]: c = np.full(len(b), np.nan)
     ...: for x in range(len(b)-1):
     ...:     c[x] = a[x+1]-b[x]
     ...: c    
Out[160]: array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  3., nan])
```

We could explore numpy methods that work without (explicit) python level iteration, but given the original error, I think you need a better handle of some basic python.